# Should i redirect to rename URI?

Tags: seo, redirects

Lets take this site, the path is

```
/questions/Question-ID/title
```

If a user writes the below it still works. On my site I was wondering if i should redirect the to the new url or let it be? what error code should i use? 302? 303?

```
/questions/Question-ID
```

Comment: I think it's a better fit in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect use a 301 as you want the redirect to be permanent.

As far as should you redirect? I don't think it's necessary. Just [use canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) so the search engines know which URL is the primary URL. I recommend having it be the one with the keywords in it.

Comment: According to that link it looks like the page should have the canonical url be `/questions/Question-ID` and it should redirect to `/questions/Question-ID/title`. Is this what i should do?

Comment: @acidzombie24: No, you either use `canonical`L or you redirect (to the canonical URL), not both. Google prefers that you use a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit to provide an unique URL for every resource in your site.
So the answer is yes, it's a good idea to redirect the user if it enters an incomplete URL.

In your case, the redirect should set a 301 HTTP Status code because you are permanently redirecting

```
/questions/Question-ID
```

to

```
/questions/Question-ID
```

This change will also reduce page duplication and help search engines to consolidate your ranking.